# Get Coordinates Of Desktop Icons with Resolution Changing C#

Tags: c#, windows, screen-resolution

I am trying to save the relative positions of desktop icons.

I am using the code found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/639486/save-and-restore-icon-positions-on-desktop) which works great on the same resolution.

I want to change the resolution and keep the icons in close to the same position as they were in the previous resolution.

I thought that would be as easy as..

```
in resolution 1280x720
x1=940
y1=398

then in resolution 800x600
x2=940(800/1280)
y2=398(600/720)
```

But this doesn't seem to be the case.

How does windows get the coordinates below when resolution is changed? What is the math here?

```
<Icons>
    <Icon x="44" y="2">Recycle Bin</Icon>
    <Icon x="44" y="101">myexe</Icon>
    <Icon x="44" y="893">New Text Document.txt</Icon>
    <Icon x="940" y="398">New Text Document (2).txt</Icon>
    <Icon x="940" y="497">New Text Document (3).txt</Icon>
    <Icon x="1836" y="2">myexe.exe</Icon>
    <Icon x="1836" y="893">desktop</Icon>
    <Icon x="44" y="200">fa.xml</Icon>
</Icons>
<Resolution x="1280" y="720" />


<Icon x="32" y="2">Recycle Bin</Icon>
<Icon x="32" y="69">myexe</Icon>
<Icon x="32" y="471">New Text Document.txt</Icon>
<Icon x="352" y="203">New Text Document (2).txt</Icon>
<Icon x="352" y="270">New Text Document (3).txt</Icon>
<Icon x="752" y="2">myexe.exe</Icon>
<Icon x="752" y="471">desktop</Icon>
<Icon x="32" y="136">fa.xml</Icon>
</Icons>
<Resolution x="800" y="600" />
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/625854/where-does-windows-store-icon-positions

Comment: You probably forgot to declare your app to be [dpiAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant I tried to add the dpiAware configuration to app.manifest but get "asmv3:" not defined

Comment: Its there, `xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3`